# laravel 5.6 error in a foreach blade view

Tags: php, laravel

During an iteration of an array of array I have this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\smartcalws\resources\views\location\index.blade.php

Below the code in the view:

```
 @foreach($Nations as $e)
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">{{$e->id}}</th>
                  <td>{{$e->name}}</td>   
 @foreach($e->districts as $d)
                  <td>{{$d->name}}</td>
      @endforeach   
 @endforeach
```

Can anyone know the why?

In the controller if I execute the foreach all work fine with the echo:

```
 foreach($Nations as $e){
   foreach($e->districts as $d){
     echo $d->name;
    }
  }
```

All nations have districts. The echo print all the districts. I thinks that the problem is in the blade page...

```
return view('Nations.index',compact('Nations',$Nations));
```

Comment: Show controller code which sets `$Nations` value. Also there can be no `districts` in `$e`, it should be checked too.

Comment: What is the relationship between `$Nation` and `districts`? Like @u_mulder said, there may be no districts returned

Comment: Nations has attributes like name, and other info and a list of districts. Both Nations and District are a collection

Comment: How did you pass that value to blade?

Answer (score 2):

The blade looks correct. Make sure you are passing the correct parameter in `Nations` to the blade view. It might be complaining about the first foreach. You need something like the following in the controller.

```
return view('yourview', [
    'Nations' => $Nations
]);
```

Perhaps also good to be consistent with working with lowercase variable names. Perhaps you are passing the key `nations` but wanting to use `Nations`.

Comment: works! The matter is the return view! I do not the why, but mine create this issue... thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is sending data to view

```
compact('Nations', $Nations) // It's wrong
```

Try these ways :

```
return view('Nations.index', compact('Nations'));
return view('Nations.index', ['Nations' => $Nations]);
return view('Nations.index')->withNations($Nations);
return view('Nations.index')->with('Nations', $Nations);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you pass the array to blade.

Also, you should put a check around your loops, if the array count is > 0